# show and hide div on checked radio button and submit form

Tags: javascript, html

I have 5 radio buttons and want to show different div on selection of particular radio 
button, but other div as contact form should be displayed on submitting form.

And one more thing I want next div on same location of first div ( first div show and second div hide at same place)

```
<p>Tell us more about Yourself</p>
    <form class="request-demo-form" action="" method="post" onSubmit="e();" name="form1">
        <div class="input-block">
            <input name="info" class="input-radio" type="radio" value="Restaurant" /> Restaurant Chain with more than 3 Locations. ( Looking for more information )
        </div>
        <div class="input-block">
            <input name="info" class="input-radio" type="radio"  value="IndRestaurant"/> Independent Restaurant with 1-3 Locations ( Looking for more information )
        </div>
        <div class="input-block">
            <input name="info" class="input-radio" type="radio" /> Existing Punchh Customers ( Looking For Support)
        </div>
        <div class="input-block">
            <input name="info" class="input-radio" type="radio" /> User of Punchh Developed App ( Looking For Support)
        </div>
        <div class="input-block">
            <input name="info" class="input-radio" type="radio" /> Others ( Marketing , Partership etc.)
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="submit-btn-area">
            <button type="submit" class="button button-dark">SUBMIT<span class="arrow1"></span></button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I have not much experience in javascript so please check my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input:radio[value="Restaurant"]').change(
        $('form').submit(function (e) {

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#main').hide();
                $('#Restaurant').show();
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        });
</script>
```

Comment: is that the full code ?

Comment: Why are you handling submit event inside change event.? and as even you are not submiting form ..you can put that code outside of `.submit` evebt

Answer (score 0):

In the above code the $(this) refers to the form element, and not the radio input field.

I suggest, that on the submit event of the form, that we check the radio input field and hide and show the divs accordingly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function (e) { 
    $('input:radio[value="Restaurant"]').is(':checked')) {
                $('#main').hide();
                $('#Restaurant').show();
                e.preventDefault();    
            }  
   });
  });
</script>
```